# php form and mysql not inserting

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm having issues with getting data from my php form into my mysql database.
I'm using mysqli by preparing the inputs, binding them and then executing.

I get no error when I submit the form. If I intentionally put an error into the prepare statement, such as mis-spelling "INERT INTO table..." then submit the form, an error does display. If I put an additional string or integer value into the bind_param, it doesn't error and if I put an additional variable or mis-spell a variable into the bind, it also doesn't error. I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong!
I've counted the number of prepared values versus the number of bound values and variables and the count matches.

Below is the input form that is being executed when submitting the form:

```
<?php
//set database connection parameters
$hostname = 'localhost:3307'; // usually is localhost
$db_user = 'test'; // change to your database username
$db_password = 'test'; // change to your database password 
$database = 'test'; // provide your database name 


//database connection
$db = new mysqli($hostname, $db_user, $db_password, $database);
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Unable to connect to database: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Prepare prerequisites
        $created = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (isset($_POST['submit']))                                                           
    {                                                                                    
    $element_1                 =htmlentities($_POST['element_1          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $element_2                 =htmlentities($_POST['element_2          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $element_3                 =htmlentities($_POST['element_3          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonTownFrom               =htmlentities($_POST['MonTownFrom        '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonPostcodeFrom           =htmlentities($_POST['MonPostcodeFrom    '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonTownTo                 =htmlentities($_POST['MonTownTo          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonPostcodeTo             =htmlentities($_POST['MonPostcodeTo      '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonMiles                  =htmlentities($_POST['MonMiles           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TueTownFrom               =htmlentities($_POST['TueTownFrom        '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TuePostcodeFrom           =htmlentities($_POST['TuePostcodeFrom    '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TueTownTo                 =htmlentities($_POST['TueTownTo          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TuePostcodeTo             =htmlentities($_POST['TuePostcodeTo      '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TueMiles                  =htmlentities($_POST['TueMiles           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedTownFrom               =htmlentities($_POST['WedTownFrom        '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedPostcodeFrom           =htmlentities($_POST['WedPostcodeFrom    '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedTownTo                 =htmlentities($_POST['WedTownTo          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedPostcodeTo             =htmlentities($_POST['WedPostcodeTo      '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedMiles                  =htmlentities($_POST['WedMiles           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuTownFrom               =htmlentities($_POST['ThuTownFrom        '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuPostcodeFrom           =htmlentities($_POST['ThuPostcodeFrom    '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuTownTo                 =htmlentities($_POST['ThuTownTo          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuPostcodeTo             =htmlentities($_POST['ThuPostcodeTo      '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuMiles                  =htmlentities($_POST['ThuMiles           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriTownFrom               =htmlentities($_POST['FriTownFrom        '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriPostcodeFrom           =htmlentities($_POST['FriPostcodeFrom    '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriTownTo                 =htmlentities($_POST['FriTownTo          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriPostcodeTo             =htmlentities($_POST['FriPostcodeTo      '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriMiles                  =htmlentities($_POST['FriMiles           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatTownFrom               =htmlentities($_POST['SatTownFrom        '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatPostcodeFrom           =htmlentities($_POST['SatPostcodeFrom    '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatTownTo                 =htmlentities($_POST['SatTownTo          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatPostcodeTo             =htmlentities($_POST['SatPostcodeTo      '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatMiles                  =htmlentities($_POST['SatMiles           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunTownFrom               =htmlentities($_POST['SunTownFrom        '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunPostcodeFrom           =htmlentities($_POST['SunPostcodeFrom    '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunTownTo                 =htmlentities($_POST['SunTownTo          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunPostcodeTo             =htmlentities($_POST['SunPostcodeTo      '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunMiles                  =htmlentities($_POST['SunMiles           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SumMiles                  =htmlentities($_POST['SumMiles           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonCheck                  =htmlentities($_POST['MonCheck           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TueCheck                  =htmlentities($_POST['TueCheck           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedCheck                  =htmlentities($_POST['WedCheck           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuCheck                  =htmlentities($_POST['ThuCheck           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriCheck                  =htmlentities($_POST['FriCheck           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatCheck                  =htmlentities($_POST['SatCheck           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunCheck                  =htmlentities($_POST['SunCheck           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonHours                  =htmlentities($_POST['MonHours           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TueHours                  =htmlentities($_POST['TueHours           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedHours                  =htmlentities($_POST['WedHours           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuHours                  =htmlentities($_POST['ThuHours           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriHours                  =htmlentities($_POST['FriHours           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatHours                  =htmlentities($_POST['SatHours           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunHours                  =htmlentities($_POST['SunHours           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SumHours                  =htmlentities($_POST['SumHours           '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonTravel                 =htmlentities($_POST['MonTravel          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TueTravel                 =htmlentities($_POST['TueTravel          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedTravel                 =htmlentities($_POST['WedTravel          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuTravel                 =htmlentities($_POST['ThuTravel          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriTravel                 =htmlentities($_POST['FriTravel          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatTravel                 =htmlentities($_POST['SatTravel          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunTravel                 =htmlentities($_POST['SunTravel          '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonMealCheck              =htmlentities($_POST['MonMealCheck       '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TueMealCheck              =htmlentities($_POST['TueMealCheck       '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedMealCheck              =htmlentities($_POST['WedMealCheck       '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuMealCheck              =htmlentities($_POST['ThuMealCheck       '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriMealCheck              =htmlentities($_POST['FriMealCheck       '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatMealCheck              =htmlentities($_POST['SatMealCheck       '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunMealCheck              =htmlentities($_POST['SunMealCheck       '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonEveningMealCheck       =htmlentities($_POST['MonEveningMealCheck'], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TueEveningMealCheck       =htmlentities($_POST['TueEveningMealCheck'], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedEveningMealCheck       =htmlentities($_POST['WedEveningMealCheck'], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuEveningMealCheck       =htmlentities($_POST['ThuEveningMealCheck'], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriEveningMealCheck       =htmlentities($_POST['FriEveningMealCheck'], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatEveningMealCheck       =htmlentities($_POST['SatEveningMealCheck'], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunEveningMealCheck       =htmlentities($_POST['SunEveningMealCheck'], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $MonOvernightCheck         =htmlentities($_POST['MonOvernightCheck  '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $TueOvernightCheck         =htmlentities($_POST['TueOvernightCheck  '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $WedOvernightCheck         =htmlentities($_POST['WedOvernightCheck  '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $ThuOvernightCheck         =htmlentities($_POST['ThuOvernightCheck  '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $FriOvernightCheck         =htmlentities($_POST['FriOvernightCheck  '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SatOvernightCheck         =htmlentities($_POST['SatOvernightCheck  '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $SunOvernightCheck         =htmlentities($_POST['SunOvernightCheck  '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $DeclarationCheck          =htmlentities($_POST['DeclarationCheck   '], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $element_68                =htmlentities($_POST['element_68         '], ENT_QUOTES); 

    //Insert the new record
    if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ap_form_1 (date_created,ip_address,element_1,element_2,element_3,element_14,element_15,element_92,element_91,element_90,element_93,element_89,element_18,element_17,element_16,element_19,element_20,element_23,element_22,element_21,element_24,element_25,element_28,element_27,element_26,element_29,element_30,element_33,element_32,element_31,element_43,element_42,element_41,element_40,element_39,element_38,element_37,element_36,element_35,element_34,SumMiles,element_44_1,element_45_1,element_46_1,element_47_1,element_48_1,element_49_1,element_50_1,element_51,element_52,element_53,element_54,element_55,element_56,element_57,SumHours,element_58,element_59,element_60,element_61,element_62,element_63,element_64,element_65_1,element_65_2,element_65_3,element_65_4,element_65_5,element_65_6,element_65_7,element_66_1,element_66_2,element_66_3,element_66_4,element_66_5,element_66_6,element_66_7,element_67_1,element_67_2,element_67_3,element_67_4,element_67_5,element_67_6,element_67_7,element_69_1,element_68)
 VALUES (?, INET_ATON(?), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
        {
        if(
        $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssissssissssissssissssissssissssiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiib', $created, $ip, $element_1, $element_2, $element_3, $MonTownFrom, $MonPostcodeFrom, $MonTownTo, $MonPostcodeTo, $MonMiles, $TueTownFrom, $TuePostcodeFrom, $TueTownTo, $TuePostcodeTo, $TueMiles, $WedTownFrom, $WedPostcodeFrom, $WedTownTo, $WedPostcodeTo, $WedMiles, $ThuTownFrom, $ThuPostcodeFrom, $ThuTownTo, $ThuPostcodeTo, $ThuMiles, $FriTownFrom, $FriPostcodeFrom, $FriTownTo, $FriPostcodeTo, $FriMiles, $SatTownFrom, $SatPostcodeFrom, $SatTownTo, $SatPostcodeTo, $SatMiles, $SunTownFrom, $SunPostcodeFrom, $SunTownTo, $SunPostcodeTo, $SunMiles, $SumMiles, $MonCheck, $TueCheck, $WedCheck, $ThuCheck, $FriCheck, $SatCheck, $SunCheck, $MonHours, $TueHours, $WedHours, $ThuHours, $FriHours, $SatHours, $SunHours, $SumHours, $MonTravel, $TueTravel, $WedTravel, $ThuTravel, $FriTravel, $SatTravel, $SunTravel, $MonMealCheck, $TueMealCheck, $WedMealCheck, $ThuMealCheck, $FriMealCheck, $SatMealCheck, $SunMealCheck, $MonEveningMealCheck, $TueEveningMealCheck, $WedEveningMealCheck, $ThuEveningMealCheck, $FriEveningMealCheck, $SatEveningMealCheck, $SunEveningMealCheck, $MonOvernightCheck, $TueOvernightCheck, $WedOvernightCheck, $ThuOvernightCheck, $FriOvernightCheck, $SatOvernightCheck, $SunOvernightCheck, $DeclarationCheck, $element_68)
        ){
        $stmt->execute();           
        }
        else
        {
        echo "ERROR: Could not bind SQL statement. Your Mileage form has not been submitted successfully.";
        printf("Bind Statement Error: %s\n", $db->error);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        }
    // show an error if the query has an error
    else
        {
        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement. Your Mileage form has not been submitted successfully.";
        printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $db->error);
        }
//      }

    }

//declare in the order variable
$db->close();
//header('Location: http://localhost/thankyou.php');
?>
```

The schema for the table is here:

```
CREATE TABLE `ap_form_1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `resume_key` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `element_1` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_2` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_3` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Drop Down',
  `element_4` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_5` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_6` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_7` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_8` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_9` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_10` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_12` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_13` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_11` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_14` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_15` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_17` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_18` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_16` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_19` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_20` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_22` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_23` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_21` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_24` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_25` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_27` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_28` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_26` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_29` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_30` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_32` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_33` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_39` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_41` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_42` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_37` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_36` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_35` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_34` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `SumMiles` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `element_31` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_43` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_40` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_38` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_65_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_65_2` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 2',
  `element_65_3` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 3',
  `element_65_4` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 4',
  `element_65_5` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 5',
  `element_65_6` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 6',
  `element_65_7` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 7',
  `element_66_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_66_2` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 2',
  `element_66_3` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 3',
  `element_66_4` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 4',
  `element_66_5` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 5',
  `element_66_6` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 6',
  `element_66_7` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 7',
  `element_67_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_67_2` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 2',
  `element_67_3` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 3',
  `element_67_4` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 4',
  `element_67_5` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 5',
  `element_67_6` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 6',
  `element_67_7` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 7',
  `element_44_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_50_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_49_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_48_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_47_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_46_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_45_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_51` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_57` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `SumHours` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `element_56` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_55` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_52` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_53` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_54` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_58` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_64` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_63` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_62` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_61` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_60` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_59` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_68` mediumtext COMMENT 'Signature',
  `element_69_1` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Checkbox - 1',
  `element_82` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_85` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_86` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_88` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_91` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_90` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_92` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_89` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  `element_93` text COMMENT 'Single Line Text',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please insert your code here, don't link to other pages.

Comment: Can you see if bind_param() returns true?

Comment: Sorry Marcel, I tried to put the code directly in but I had trouble with the block code insertion

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what is being tested in the if statement.
You'll see that you are only checking to see if preparing the statement had an error.  You don't check to see if the actual execution of the query.

You can add an additional if statement to the execution of the query to let you know if there is an issue.

> and it only seems to be inserting the date and the ip address (first
>   two variables) and nothing else

The issue you have with not seeing any of the other variables is because they aren't defined.  Since you're submitting data from a form, you need to access them using $_POST or $_GET.  Take a look at php's [guide on external variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

Also, if you update your main post with the new code and any new errors, we can help you narrow things down.

Comment: The error shown was:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(' in input.php on line 38
Line 38 is the bind_param statement

Comment: I've counted the number of bind parameters versus the number of variables being passed for binding and the count is the same. 86.

Comment: A parse error means that PHP ran into an error, not the SQL serverr.
If you could, update your post with the new code so I can take a look at it.  Then, comment so I see that you've done it.

Comment: Yep, looks like my if else statement was incorrect. I've fixed that, but it's still not reporting an error and it's also not inserting data.
I've put in:
echo "Inserted {$created}, {$ip}, {$element_1}, {$element_2}, {$element_3}, {$MonTownFrom} etc etc into database" into the code, to see what it's putting in, and it only seems to be inserting the date and the ip address (first two variables) and nothing else. That data however isn't even being written to the mysql server :(

Comment: An example of what is being inserted is:

`code`
 <td> Name: <span id="required_61" class="required">*</span></td>
<td><input name="element_1" type="text" id="element_1" class="formfield" value=""/></td>
<td> Employee Ref: *</td>
<td><input name="element_2" type="text" id="element_2" class="formfield" value=""/></td>
`code`

Comment: Updated my answer for the next issue.

Comment: The full output from the submit is:

Inserted 03-05-2013 00:03:28, 127.0.0.1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , into database

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code with the new if, else statement.

Comment: Ok. I've now added in the code to grab the posted variables so they can be defined.
Every variable now has the following error:
Notice: Undefined index: element_1 in input.php on line 23
Notice: Undefined index: element_2 in input.php on line 24
etc etc.

Comment: For this issue,  keys have to match what's in them EXACTLY.  All of those extra spaces mess up the lookup.

Comment: Damn, and I was going for pretty!

Comment: Ok, so things are going well after removing the white space. The problem I'm encountering now is that any checkboxes that are not checked are having an undefined index error:
Notice: Undefined index: MonCheck in input.php on line 65

I was under the impression that the "if (isset" was going to take care of this but it doesn't look like it has.
Any ideas?

Comment: According to your code, you're only checking to see if $_POST isset.  
If a checkbox is not checked in the form, it isn't passed to the following page.  So, you'll have to check for each of them.  Though, honestly, you should do that with every field and set a default.